# clean water with any coloring could be viewed as cloudy, is my understanding right?

Tags: meaning

This video is [showing](https://youtu.be/WpzL-yavSdM?t=30) some cloudy water.

[cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cloudy) explains cloudy as "not transparent".

According to which, I guess clean water with any coloring could be viewed as cloudy, adding something like mud could also be viewed as cloudy, is my understanding right?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking up "cloudy" in a dictionary?  If so, what did you find?

Comment: In scientific terms (in the particular context here), water is usually referred to as “cloudy” when there are particles suspended in the water so that it is no longer *entirely* transparent. Here the particles reflect back some of the light so you can see the laser as it passes through the water. Notice that “cloudy” derives from the word “cloud”, but you don’t need to see individual “clouds” and the air or water referred to may be uniformly “clouded” (as it is here).

Comment: Coloured water could still be clear (i.e. not cloudy).